# remove trailing slashes recursively on php files on windows with cmder

Tags: sed, cmder

I need to remove all trailing slashes on php files. I use cmder on windows.

I use this command to find the files, but they are a lot.

```
find ./ -name "*.php" | xargs grep -c -P '\s+$' | grep -v ':0$'
```

I found this but I do not know howto use it:

```
sed -i 's/[ \t]*$//' "$1"
```